# How to handle authentication with ServiceStack for SPA website?

Tags: authentication, servicestack, single-page-application

I started developing small application with ServiceStack. I plan to create small Single-Page-Application website. I started wondering do I really need any kind of ASP.Net, because all client logic will be handled by angular in pure html pages, I don't really need i.e. Razor. I have only one concern - authentication. I'd like to use user-password, facebook and google authentications. Someone has to handle it, I'm thinking about forms authentication from MVC like in https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc
but this way I'd have to add MVC libraries only for the sake of authentication. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [section on Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks/blob/master/README.md#authentication) in ServiceStack's documented [Http Benchmarks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks/) example which walks through how to setup both Credentials-based Authentication and Registration (i.e. Username/Password) as well as Twitter, Facebook, Google and LinkedIn OAuth providers.

ServiceStack's [docs on Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) and [Sessions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) are also useful in learning about Authentication in ServiceStack.

Comment: Yes, I've seen Http Benchmark example, but they use ASP.Net MVC there. MY question was - is it possible to do authentication without MVC framework, only with ServiceStack. I know that ServiceStack contains mechanism to handle authentication for REST services, but my main concern are html pages - how to set that anonymous users have access to given pages and where should be redirected to log in? I know how to do that using MVC and Forms authentication, is it possible to do using pure service stack?

Comment: @Twelve HttpBenchmarks doesn't have any dependency on ASP.NET MVC, it just uses ServiceStack's Razor. [ServiceStack Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat) is another very simple Single Page App that allows Anonymous users as well as authentication via OAuth.

Comment: I checked HttpBenchmark project and now I understand better how ServiceStack handles authentication. I have still one question though - in ViewPage class there is method RedirectIfNotAuthenticated(), do you have to use it on any page you want to be restricted? Can you set somewhere that all pages are restricted and you can't access them, you can only login on this one publicly available? Also is there some kind of equivalent of RedirectIfNotAuthenticated method for pure html pages, to disallow user access to given html page?

Comment: @Twelve the Razor View helpers are just convenience methods, you can call `/auth` to find out if they're logged in or not, it returns a `401 Unauthenticated` if they're not.